# MVC Making more than one search to get product by id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC view i want to create search to get product by id , But not one search i want more than one search that cause the customer want more than product 
`

```
public ActionResult Search(int pid ,int pid2 ,int pid3)
        {
            var products = (from d in db.Products
                            where d.ProductId == pid || d.ProductId == pid2 || d.ProductId == pid2
                       select d).ToList();



            return View(products);
        }`
```

[view show what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTtc3.jpg)

When i try to do this with this code ,all search results be the same result

Comment: Sorry ! Your question is still unclear to me. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Can you post the exact exception/error that you are getting?

Comment: Look to the photo under the code .. all search box show the same result for one search [this photo to show what i mean https://41.media.tumblr.com/bf060a28b9d07ec38aa8096692fb18be/tumblr_o2t0p8KYBd1swp9s3o1_540.jpg ]

Comment: on this I think the problem is that you are populating the view with the result and all the results are posted to the same ID or class hence showing the same product three times. Remember there is no state here so one click will make one call and response. I don't see why you need three searchbox on the same page

Answer (score 0):

This is arm chair coded so it might take a little finessing to actually work but you want something like:

```
public ActionResult Search(IEnumerable<int> productIds)
{
    var products = (from d in db.Products 
          where productIds.Contains(d.ProductId);
          select d).ToList();

            return View(products);
}
```

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ is also likely relevant here.

A different topic is you should not be doing database calls inside a controller. You should move your database logic to a separate class and then use constructor injection to pass that class instance to your controller.